# Why is cartesian product of $A\times\varnothing=\varnothing$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am studying some preliminaries of set theory.

I have a question why is Cartesian Product of $A\times\varnothing=\varnothing$ not the set $\{(a,\varnothing)~\mid~a\text{ belongs to }A \}$ using the definition of $A\times B=\{ (a, b)~\mid~a\text{ belongs to }A,~b\text{ belongs to }B\}$?

Can someone please explain!

Comment: Assume that the left side is non-empty and get a  contradiction.

Comment: Please use `\emptyset` or `\varnothing` for the empty set rather than `\phi`. The empty set symbol is completely unrelated to the Greek letter, and is instead the Norwegian letter ø.

Comment: It helps to replace the mathematical [colloquialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloquialism) "a belongs to A , b belongs to B" with "(a belongs to A) and (b belongs to B)". Since nothing satisfies "b belongs to B", it follows from [the meaning of *and*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) that there are no ordered pairs (a,b) which satisfy the criteria for membership into the set, and thus the set is the empty set (i.e. the set has no elements).

Comment: Probably not a proof by first principles, but its consistent with the fact that $|A\times B| = |A|\times|B|$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> using the definition of $A\times B=\{ (a, b)~\mid~a\text{ belongs to }A,~b\text{ belongs to }B\}$

So use that definition properly to get
$$
A\times\varnothing=\{(a,b)\mid a\in A\text{ and }b\in \varnothing\}
$$
How many possibilities do we have for $b$ here, would you say? Note that while $\varnothing\subseteq\varnothing$, we have $\varnothing\notin\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0):

The set $A×B$ is defined by $ A×B = \{(a,b)|a\in A \wedge b\in B \}$ but $a\in A \wedge b\in B$ is never satisfied if either $A$ or $B$ is $\emptyset$.